# Asking for some clarification in java about jlabel and parent

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, parent, jlabel

Found this code in the internet, it was posted years ago, so I just decided to ask here for some clarifications for some lines I don't quite understand.

In the `mousePressed` method, what does he mean by:
`chessPiece = null` is he saying that if the `JLabel chessPiece` has a image in it then it should be changed to `null`?

Is `chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY())` returns the `JPanel` square?

and lastly, when `Component c` gets its parent, who is the parent?

The whole code is below:

```
public class ChessGameDemo extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    JLayeredPane layeredPane;
    JPanel chessBoard;
    JLabel chessPiece;
    int xAdjustment;
    int yAdjustment;
    private static final String imageFolderPath = "src/resources/images/";

    public ChessGameDemo() {
        Dimension boardSize = new Dimension(600, 600);

        //  Use a Layered Pane for this this application
        layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        getContentPane().add(layeredPane);
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize(boardSize);
        layeredPane.addMouseListener(this);
        layeredPane.addMouseMotionListener(this);

         //Add a chess board to the Layered Pane 
        chessBoard = new JPanel();
        layeredPane.add(chessBoard, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        chessBoard.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
        chessBoard.setPreferredSize(boardSize);
        chessBoard.setBounds(0, 0, boardSize.width, boardSize.height);

        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            JPanel square = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            chessBoard.add(square);

            int row = (i / 8) % 2;
            if (row == 0) {
                square.setBackground(i % 2 == 0 ? Color.blue : Color.white);
            } else {
                square.setBackground(i % 2 == 0 ? Color.white : Color.blue);
            }
        }

          //Add a few pieces to the board
        JLabel piece = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imageFolderPath + "/pieces/bdg.png"));
        JPanel panel = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(0);
        panel.add(piece);
        piece = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imageFolderPath + "/pieces/belder.png"));
        panel = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(15);
        panel.add(piece);
        piece = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imageFolderPath + "/pieces/bhero.png"));
        panel = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(16);
        panel.add(piece);
        piece = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imageFolderPath + "/pieces/borb.png"));
        panel = (JPanel) chessBoard.getComponent(20);
        panel.add(piece);

    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        chessPiece = null;
        Component c = chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());

        if (c instanceof JPanel) {
            return;
        }

        Point parentLocation = c.getParent().getLocation();
        xAdjustment = parentLocation.x - e.getX();
        yAdjustment = parentLocation.y - e.getY();
        chessPiece = (JLabel) c;
        chessPiece.setLocation(e.getX() + xAdjustment, e.getY() + yAdjustment);
        chessPiece.setSize(chessPiece.getWidth(), chessPiece.getHeight());
        layeredPane.add(chessPiece, JLayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER);
    }

        //Move the chess piece around
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
        if (chessPiece == null) {
            return;
        }
        chessPiece.setLocation(me.getX() + xAdjustment, me.getY() + yAdjustment);
    }

         //Drop the chess piece back onto the chess board
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if (chessPiece == null) {
            return;
        }

        chessPiece.setVisible(false);
        Component c = chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());

        if (c instanceof JLabel) {
            Container parent = c.getParent();
            parent.remove(0);
            parent.add(chessPiece);
        } else {
            Container parent = (Container) c;
            parent.add(chessPiece);
        }
        ....
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the `mousePiece` method, what does he mean by: `chessPiece = null` is
>   he saying that if the `JLabel chessPiece` has a image in it then it
>   should be changed to `null`?

I assume you mean `mousePressed`.  By using `chessPiece = null`, the author is de-referencing the variable, so what ever was assigned to it is no longer reachable through the is variable

> Is `chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY())` returns the `JPanel` square?

This depends.  `findComponentAt` can search the current container and it's any of it's child containers until it finds a component at the specified position.  Technquial, the author is ignoring the component that triggered the event (which should `layeredPane`) and is walking the `chessBoard` instead.  I suspect they are doing this because if they used `layeredPane` it would return `chessBoard` instead.

The method is capable of returning `JPanel`, `JLabel` and possibly even `null`, but given the way that the components are laid out, it's a lower probability.

> and lastly, when Component c gets its parent, who is the parent?

This depends.  Based on my understanding of the code, I would say it's return a `JPanel` underneth the `JLabel` piece.

Have to say, there are easier ways to achieve the same result though...

Comment: +1 for understanding my confused brain. _Technquial, the author is ignoring the component that triggered the event (which should layeredPane)_ - good point. _Have to say, there are easier ways to achieve the same result though_ - doesn't surprise me. I was never very good at calculating relative positions when dragging components... :)

Comment: @camickr Lol, the internet never forgets ;)

Answer (score 3):

> In the mousePressed method, what does he mean by:

The purpose of the class is to drag a label from one square to another. So there is code in the `mouseDragged` and `mouseReleased` events to 1) do the dragging of the label on the layered pane and 2) drop the label onto the appropriate square.

However, if the user didn't click on a square containing a label then the above code should not be executed, so the chessPiece is initially set to null and the code in the above two method is only executed when a chessPiece was clicked on.

> Is chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY()) returns the JPanel square?

If it returns a JPanel, then that means there is NO chessPiece (JLabel) on the square where the user clicked. Since there is no chessPiece there is nothing to be dragged.

If it returns a JLabel, then that means there IS a chessPiece where the user clicked. In this case addition code is executed to add the chessPiece to the layered pane so it can be dragged.

> when Component c gets its parent, who is the parent?

It's the JPanel containing the label. Since the label is added to the layered pane for dragging it needs to be positioned at the same location on the layered pane relative to the panel square on the chessboard.

Here is a slightly updated version that checks the bounds of the chess piece as it is dragged so it can't be moved off of the chess board. Also adds the mouse listeners to the chess board not the layered pane so the findComponentAt() method is more consistent.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ChessBoard extends JLayeredPane implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{
    JLayeredPane layeredPane;
    JPanel chessBoard;
    JLabel chessPiece;
    int xAdjustment;
    int yAdjustment;

    public ChessBoard()
    {
        Dimension boardSize = new Dimension(600, 600);
        setPreferredSize( boardSize );

        //  Add a chess board to the Layered Pane

        chessBoard = new JPanel();
        chessBoard.setLayout( new GridLayout(8, 8) );
        chessBoard.setPreferredSize( boardSize );
        chessBoard.setBounds(0, 0, boardSize.width, boardSize.height);
        chessBoard.addMouseListener( this );
        chessBoard.addMouseMotionListener( this );
        add(chessBoard, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

        //  Build the Chess Board squares

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                JPanel square = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
                square.setBackground( (i + j) % 2 == 0 ? Color.red : Color.white );
                chessBoard.add( square );
            }
        }

        // Add a few pieces to the board

        ImageIcon duke = new ImageIcon("dukewavered.gif"); // add an image here

        JLabel piece = new JLabel( duke );
        JPanel panel = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent( 0 );
        panel.add( piece );
        piece = new JLabel( duke );
        panel = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent( 15 );
        panel.add( piece );
    }

    /*
    **  Add the selected chess piece to the dragging layer so it can be moved
    */
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        chessPiece = null;
        Component c =  chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());

        if (c instanceof JPanel) return;

        Point parentLocation = c.getParent().getLocation();
        xAdjustment = parentLocation.x - e.getX();
        yAdjustment = parentLocation.y - e.getY();
        chessPiece = (JLabel)c;
        chessPiece.setLocation(e.getX() + xAdjustment, e.getY() + yAdjustment);

        add(chessPiece, JLayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER);
        setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR));
    }

    /*
    **  Move the chess piece around
    */
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me)
    {
        if (chessPiece == null) return;

        //  The drag location should be within the bounds of the chess board

        int x = me.getX() + xAdjustment;
        int xMax = chessBoard.getWidth() - chessPiece.getWidth();
        x = Math.min(x, xMax);
        x = Math.max(x, 0);

        int y = me.getY() + yAdjustment;
        int yMax = chessBoard.getHeight() - chessPiece.getHeight();
        y = Math.min(y, yMax);
        y = Math.max(y, 0);

        chessPiece.setLocation(x, y);
     }

    /*
    **  Drop the chess piece back onto the chess board
    */
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        setCursor(null);

        if (chessPiece == null) return;

        //  Make sure the chess piece is no longer painted on the layered pane

        chessPiece.setVisible(false);
        remove(chessPiece);
        chessPiece.setVisible(true);

        //  The drop location should be within the bounds of the chess board

        int xMax = chessBoard.getWidth() - chessPiece.getWidth();
        int x = Math.min(e.getX(), xMax);
        x = Math.max(x, 0);

        int yMax = chessBoard.getHeight() - chessPiece.getHeight();
        int y = Math.min(e.getY(), yMax);
        y = Math.max(y, 0);

        Component c =  chessBoard.findComponentAt(x, y);

        if (c instanceof JLabel)
        {
            Container parent = c.getParent();
            parent.remove(0);
            parent.add( chessPiece );
            parent.revalidate();
        }
        else
        {
            Container parent = (Container)c;
            parent.add( chessPiece );
            parent.revalidate();
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chess Board");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.add( new ChessBoard() );
        frame.setResizable( false );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```