# Adding multiple JPanels to JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing

I am writing a chess program. For displaying the chessboard I am using two `JPanel`s:

1. **chessboard:** This panel displays an image of an empty chessboard
2. **chessmen:** This panel displays an array of `JLabel`s with chessmen images

So for this I need the two panels on top of each other. Therefore I am presently using a `JLayeredPane`. But the problem is I can only view only one of the layers at once.

My present code for the constructor is:

```
public ChessBoard(){

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    gamescreen = new JLayeredPane();
    gamescreen.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));

    chessboard = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    chessmen = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    //chessboard.setLocation(0, 0);
    //chessmen.setLocation(0,0);

    chessboardImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("chessboard.jpg"));
    chessboardDisplay = new  JLabel(chessboardImage);

    chessboard.add(chessboardDisplay);
    GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++){

            imageSet[i][j] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(""+i+(j+1)+".png"));
            image = imageSet[i][j].getImage().getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            imageSet[i][j]= new ImageIcon(image);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        constraint.gridy=i+3000;
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
            chessmenPos[i][j] = new JLabel(imageSet[i][j]);
            constraint.gridx=j;
            chessmen.add(chessmenPos[i][j],constraint);
        }

        chessboard.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
        chessmen.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);


        gamescreen.add(chessboard, 1);
        gamescreen.add(chessmen, 0);

        gamescreen.setOpaque(false);
        chessboard.setVisible(true);
        chessmen.setVisible(true);
        add(gamescreen);
    }

    EventHandling eventHandler = new EventHandling();
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
            chessmenPos[i][j].addMouseListener(eventHandler);

}
```

Where am I going wrong and what changes can I make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the problem is I can only view only one of the layers at once.

The top layer needs to be transparent. So you would need:

```
chessmen.setOpaque( false );
```

You can check out: [Asking for some clarification in java about jlabel and parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343047/asking-for-some-clarification-in-java-about-jlabel-and-parent/22357889#22357889) for an example of a simple chessboard. It uses a slightly different approach. Each square is a component.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just realised I was setting the wrong panel as transparent